# Why $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} I(z)=\oint_{\gamma} \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}\left(\frac{1}{\zeta-z}\right) d \zeta$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, cauchy-integral-formula

Well,I  just started to study complex analysis,with the textbook "Function Theory of One Complex Variable".In section 2.4,I encountered the following problem:

Let $\gamma$ be the boundary of a disc $D\left(z_{0}, r\right)$ in the complex plane, equipped with counterclockwise orientation. Let $z$ be a point insic the circle $\partial D\left(z_{0}, r\right) .$
Let $$I(z)=\oint_{\gamma} \frac{1}{\zeta-z} d \zeta$$
Then $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} I(z)=\oint_{\gamma} \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}\left(\frac{1}{\zeta-z}\right) d \zeta$$
Also,$$\frac{\partial}{\partial z} I(z)=\oint_{\gamma} \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(\frac{1}{\zeta-z}\right) d \zeta$$
I don't know why it does work.For real function,We may use Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem .But for complex case,how to prove that?Can someone give a hint or detailed solution?Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with using dominated convergence for complex functions?

Comment: @Ninad Munshi I know that if $f$ is complex-valued function,Then Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem also make sense.So I can exchange the order of differentiation and integration in some special case.My doubt is about how to $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} I(z)$.According、

Comment: @Ninad Munshi According to the definition,$ \frac{\partial}{\partial z} f \equiv \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-i \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) f=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right)+\frac{i}{2}\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right).$But  it seems difficult to prove  conclusion in this way.